# How to draw a divider having Text in middle of it in android?

Tags: android

I need your help in drawing this picture down below  in android . Any Suggestions much appreciated ?

[image: Logo]

Answer (score 3):

**To make this divider**

[image: this]

**Copy and paste it**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="11"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/line1"
        style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:background="#ef0202" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="OR"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/line2"
        style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:background="#ef0202" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply . I will upvote your answer.

Comment: @Srikanth86in I've edited xml recently. To make it same as you shown. Will it be OK ?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna The first and third children can be `View`s instead of `TextView`s, and they don't need the `style`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion bro, But I don't think its really necessary to be edited, People will use as per their need.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the help of canvas and paint

```
   Paint paint = new Paint();
     canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 20, 20, paint);
paint.setColor(Color.Red); 
  canvas.drawText("OR", 10, 25, paint); 
   canvas.drawLine(10 0, 20, 20, paint);
```

I hope this works. ThankYou.